# Get Data From Post Request Angular/.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having trouble getting a JSON response from a POST Request from my .Net Core server. In essence I would be using this POST request like a GET request from the server. I believe I'm passing in the correct headers, however, in my console error I'm getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessionId' of undefined

I suspect it's something that has to do with the type and/or model. Or possibly how I'm calling it in the service. If I need to add anything for clarification, lmk.

*.NET CORE Server Code*

**Action.Dto**

```
{
public class ActionDto
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public Tag ActionTag { get; set; }
    public ActionParams Args { get; set; }
}
```

}

**ActionService.cs**

```
    {
    ActionResponse LaunchAction(string sessionId, Tag actionTag, ActionParams args, UserState userState);
}
```

**Action Controller**

```
 public IActionResult LaunchAction([FromBody]ActionDto launchActionParameters)
    {
        var sessionId = launchActionParameters.SessionId;
        var actionTag = launchActionParameters.ActionTag;
        var args = launchActionParameters.Args;
        UserState userState = null;
        RunAction runAction = null;
```

*Angular Client Code*

**Action Component**

```
       export interface ActionView {
  actionName: string;
  actionType: string;
  primaryTable: string;
  specialUse: string;
  folder: string;
  actionDescription: string;
  actionTag: number;
  chartType: string;
  priority: number;
}

const ACTION_DATA: ActionView[] = [];

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    // User Fields
    currentUser: User;
    users: User[] = [];
    currentUserSubscription: Subscription;

    // Action Fields
    currentAction: Action;
    actions: Action[]  = [];


    displayedColumns: string[] =
    ['actionName', 'actionType', 'primaryTable', 'specialUse',
    'folder', 'actionDescription', 'actionTag', 'chartType',
     'priority'];

    dataSource: any = new MatTableDataSource(ACTION_DATA);

    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private actionService: ActionService
    ) {
        this.currentUserSubscription = this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
            this.currentUser = user;
        });
        this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
          'thumbs-up',
         this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'));
    }

    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

   public getActions() {
      console.log('test');

      this.actionService.getActions(
        this.currentAction).subscribe((data) => {
          this.dataSource = data;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.getActions();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.currentUserSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**Action Service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ActionService {

  public apiURL = 'http://localhost:15217/api';
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  public currentAction: Observable<Action>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
      // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  getActions(action: Action): Observable<Action[]> {
    return this.http.post<Action[]>(this.apiURL + '/actions/launchactions',
    {
        sessionId: action.sessionId,
        tag: action.actionTag,
        actionParams: action.actionParams
     })
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

    // Error handling
    handleError(error: any) {
      let errorMessage = '';
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // Get client-side error
        errorMessage = error.error.message;
      } else {
        // Get server-side error
        errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
      }
      window.alert(errorMessage);
      return throwError(errorMessage);
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked value of currenAction before calling post? If you are using post to get values, you should pass data in body and not in params

Comment: Any update...i still need help with this

Answer (score 1):

add [FromBody] to controller side service, before the parameter. Post method pass parameters in body.

like

```
ActionResponse LaunchAction([FromBody]string sessionId, [FromBody]Tag actionTag, [FromBody]ActionParams args, [FromBody]UserState userState);
```

I don't know why microsoft did not decide to do this default.

Comment: thanks.. still getting an error of Cannot read property 'sessionId' of undefined. wonder what i'm missing

Comment: @KoryJ.Campbell oh I got it, you don't even reach the controller side. But you will need to add this to controller too. on action component, did you check if this  this.currentAction is really assigned or is it null?

Comment: yeah it seems that I may be missing something that I'm not reaching the server.

Comment: @KoryJ.Campbell on action component, did you check if this this.currentAction is really assigned or is it null?

Comment: currentAction is returning as undefined

Comment: @KoryJ.Campbell yes. you need to assign it properly first.

Comment: & what am I doing wrong above where it's not being assigned properly?

Comment: @kjamp I don't know what you do in the rest of your code, where do you set this currentAction.sessionId?

Comment: I just updated the action service angular code and action .net core controller... but it's set from there

Comment: @kjamp if you upload that part of your code somewhere accessible, like github, I can take a look.

Comment: definitely could use the help thank you https://gist.github.com/KoryJCampbell/c57f7bc861d636a386023c4e55ed7624

Comment: any luck? still stuck with this

Comment: hello @kjamp, I looked at your code and do not understand what are you trying to achieve with this part         this.currentActionSubscription = this.actionService.currentAction.subscribe(action => {
          this.currentAction = action;
        });

Comment: And, in the service, you are not assigning any value ->here you define:  public currentAction: Observable<Action>; and here you assign in your constructor : this.currentAction = this.currentActionSubject.asObservable(); why do you use it as observable, just make a public parameter, and access it, create a method to share it if you don't want to make it accessable.

Comment: instead of public currentAction: Observable<Action> do public currentAction: Action

Comment: instead of  this.currentAction = this.currentActionSubject.asObservable(); do  this.currentAction = this.currentActionSubject.[what you need];

Comment: and create a method like GetAction():Action{ return this.currentAction;} in your actual code instead of  this.currentActionSubscription = this.actionService.currentAction.subscribe(action => {
          this.currentAction = action;
        }); do this.currentAction = this.actionService.GetAction(); and put a breakpoint on service to see if currentAction is null or not.

Comment: hmm ok .... this helps but i have one last question.. i don't understand the this.currentActionSubject.[what you need]; part. I'm unsure what goes in that array, and how to set it

Comment: Actually I did not notice that this part creates confusion, I just don't know do you need the entire object or just one property of the object, that is why I added this part, you can ignore if you need the object itself, but if you need student id for example, you can use like student.studentId.

Comment: Yeah I would need the entire object... but it looks like I'm getting errors in the service because it still is using actions as an observable

Answer (score 0):

You should remove {} from data: {}
By doing this you are assigning an empty object to that

Comment: removed thanks for this tidbit. I'm still getting my original error however

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the "params" word from your angular http post call ?

So the http post call is this instead

```
return this.http.post<Action[]>(this.apiURL + '/actions/launchactions', 
     {
        sessionId: action.sessionId,
        tag: action.actionTag,
        actionParams: action.actionParams
     })
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

Comment: I believe this may help, but my issue is probably because of this.currentAction returning as undefined?

Comment: it could be. It's not clear from the code snippet that you provided, whether you have assign currentAction  or not

Comment: based from the updated code snippet that you provided, the value of currentAction seems to be null when you pass it to Action Service.You'll need to assign the value of currentAction before you call this.getActions() in ngOnInit

Comment: just updated the code; but I think it would be assigned in the service or am I wrong? I thought I did that assignment in the service

Comment: I don't think you ever assign this value anywhere in your Action Component's code. So technically you pass a null object in when you call getActions().

In the Action Service's code you actually try to read the value of currentAction as request body to your .Net Core server. But because currentAction null, the console print that error.

Comment: So i looked through my code and I thought I assigned value to currentActions in the getActions public function.... the data source would be from the getActions function?
subscription